# No entiendo el siguiente error en este codigo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando crear este código para simular una biblioteca y no entiendo por qué salta el siguiente error:

> in  MostrarMenu() NameError: name 'MostrarMenu' is not defined;

Hay una clase para definir los libros, y otra clase para definir los autores. Esa es la clase biblioteca donde me da fallo.

```
class Biblioteca:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ListaLibros = []
    def NumeroLibros(self):
        return len(self.ListaLibros)
    def AñadirLibros(self,libro):
        self.ListaLibros = self.ListaLibros + [libro]
    def MostrarBiblioteca(self):
        print ("#############################")
        for item in self.ListaLibros:
            item.MostrarLibro()
        print ("#############################")
    def BorrarLibro(self,titulo):
        encontrado = False
        posicionaborrar = -1
        for item in self.ListaLibros:
            posicionaborrar +=1
            if item.ObtenerTitulo() == titulo:
                encontrado = True
                break
            if encontrado:
                del self.ListaLibros[posicionaborrar]
                print ("Libro borrado correctamente")
            else:
                print ("Libro no encontrado")
    def MostrarMenu():
        print ("MENU 1)Añadir Libro \n2)Mostrar Biblioteca \n3)Borrar Libro \n4)¿Número de libros? \n5)Salir")
    def AñadirLibroABiblioteca(biblioteca):
        titulo = input("Introduzca el titulo: ")
        autornombre = input("Introduzca nombre del autor: ")
        autorapellido = input("Introduzca apellidos del autor: ")
        autor = Autor(nombre,apellidos)
        libro = Libro(titulo)
        libro.AñadirAutor(autor)
        biblioteca.AñadirLibro(libro)
        return biblioteca
    def MostrarBiblioteca(biblioteca):
        biblioteca.MostrarBiblioteca()
    def BorrarLibro(biblioteca):
        titulo = input("Introduzca el titulo del libro a borrar")
        biblioteca.BorrarLibro(titulo)
    def NumeroLibros(biblioteca):
        print ("El número de libros en la biblioteca es: ",biblioteca.NumeroLibros())

fin = False
biblioteca = Biblioteca()

while fin is False:
    MostrarMenu()
    opcion = int(input("Seleccione una opcion:"))
    if (opcion == 1):
        biblioteca = AñadirLibroABiblioteca(biblioteca)
    elif (opcion == 2):
        MostrarBiblioteca(biblioteca)
    elif (opcion == 3):
        BorrarLibro(biblioteca)
    elif (opcion == 4):
        NumeroLibros(biblioteca)
    elif (opcion == 5):
        fin = True

print ("Hasta pronto")
```

Answer (score 2):

El error sale porque `MostrarMenu` es una función estática definida dentro de `Biblioteca`. Al ser una función estática puedes llamarla de dos formas diferentes:

```
while fin is False:
    Biblioteca.MostrarMenu() # opcion 1 - acceso via el nombre de la clase
    biblioteca.MostrarMenu() # opcion 2 - acceso via instancia de la clase
```

Bueno, la segunda opción como tal no va a funcionar directamente. Para que funcione hay que declarar previamente el método como estático (Gracias a [@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia) por darse cuenta del detalle):

```
class Biblioteca:
    @staticmethod
    def MostrarMenu():
```

El resto de llamadas también están mal ya que son funciones miembros de biblioteca. En este caso no son funciones estáticas, luego necesitas la una instancia de `Biblioteca` como punto de partida:

```
if (opcion == 1):
    biblioteca.AñadirLibroABiblioteca()
elif (opcion == 2):
    biblioteca.MostrarBiblioteca()
elif (opcion == 3):
    biblioteca.BorrarLibro()
elif (opcion == 4):
    biblioteca.NumeroLibros()
elif (opcion == 5):
    fin = True
```

En otro orden de cosas, te sugiero separar las funciones con una o dos líneas en blanco... Tener todo el código compactado no va a facilitar su lectura ni su mantenimiento

Comment: La segunda opción que pones al principio: `biblioteca.MostrarMenu()` fallará al intentar pasar como parámetro `biblioteca` al método, ya que en éste no se declaro `self` como parámetro. Sólo funcionará por tanto la primera forma `Biblioteca.MostrarMenu()`.  Para que pudieran funcionar ambas, debería aparecer el decorador `@staticmethod` delante de la definición de ese método.

Comment: @abulafia cierto, se me pasó